# How to bind a key to issue two commands in visual mode?

Tags: vim, clipboard

This question is more general than the problem I am currently faced with, and may not have a solution. But my real problem may have a solution if there is no general solution.

What I want to do is if I use `y` from visual mode, I want Vim to yank both to the `+` register and to the regular `"` register.

I don't care about clobbering the system clipboard, because there are tools I use to record past clipboard entries. I just want a way to yank to clipboard which is easy enough to perform that I may actually make use of it.

Possible approaches

- bind key to function which somehow hopefully can grab the range of the selection, and then stick it into both registers -- i think this can be done, i have a magic snippet in my vimrc that does this. I have no idea how it works. Looks like this: `vnoremap <silent> x :<C-u>execute 'normal! vlF' . nr2char(getchar()) . 'of' . nr2char(getchar())<CR>`
- yank and then call function that explicitly copies `"` register to `+` register. Not sure how to do a yank and then call some function. might be easier
- ???
- no direct profit likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set clipboard^=unnamedplus
```

See `:help 'clipboard'`.

> I don't care about clobbering the system clipboard, because there are tools I use to record past clipboard entries. I just want a way to yank to clipboard which is easy enough to perform that I may actually make use of it.

Clobbering the system clipboard is precisely a rather big issue with synchronizing the unnamed register and the clipboard register *when you use a system-wide clipboard manager.* It becomes hard to find what you are looking for, which is probably buried below dozens upon dozens of meaningless entries. Think about that.

Another option could be to remap `y` in visual mode to yank to the system clipboard:

```
 xnoremap y "+y
```

Since *all* yanks are sent to the unnamed register no matter what, the command above will effectively yank the visual selection to the unnamed register *and* the clipboard register. This is in my opinion a much cleaner solution than using `'clipboard'`.

Comment: Yeah i wanted to only have visual mode `y` to yank to system clipboard so that i wont end up with a ton of useless entries. I guess you brought up a really good point at the end there, which is... all yanks always go into `"` so I really didnt need to even find or write a way to bind two actions to the key.

Comment: This works well. I didn't mention... I can't actually even type `"+y` in visual mode, because my `"` is bound to `surround.vim` to surround selection with double-quotes.